# How can I find all users in Ubuntu and show information for users from parameter when I launch bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I know only one solution - watch file /etc/passwd
but how can I launch script with argument, for example like this

```
./myscript user_name
```

and get info about specific user ?

My script looks like this

```
grep home /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

but if there is no arguments - show info about all users in system

Comment: So, what does your script look like?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I hope what you are asking is how to pass arguments to bash scriept.
Use

```
./myscript user_name
```

And in the script access it as

```
username=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for this.

myscript

```
user=$1; 
grep home /etc/passwd | grep $user | cut -d: -f1;
```

you must use grep for showing result of particular single user.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, but I can see only name without other information

Comment: If you want to see full information then remove " | cut -d: -f1; " from command, which wlll be " grep home /etc/passwd | grep $user ".

Answer (score 0):

awk -F: '{ system ("./myscript "$1)}' /etc/passwd

Take the first piece of the data on each line of /etc/passwd ($1) separated by : and then use this in the system function to execute your myscript script.

Answer (score 0):

`getent passwd $user_name | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, but using your command I can see only name without any other information

Comment: Isn't that what you were asking for in your question?